Missing mysqli extension on PHP container
I'm trying to create a web server with docker that contains 3 virtual hosts: One is a normal HTML page with PHP that works correctly and the rest are wordpress from different domains. For this I have 2 wordpress containers, 1 mysql:5.7 database, 1 nginx server and 1 php
There is the docker compose:
    services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./mugen-metrics:/var/www/mugen-metrics
      - ./ukiyo-way:/var/www/ukiyo-way
      - ./ws-project:/var/www/ws-project
      - ./nginx-logs:/var/log/nginx
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
      - wordpress2
      - php
    networks:
      - app-network

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    container_name: wordpress_ukiyo-way
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb
    volumes:
      - ./ukiyo-way:/var/www/ukiyo-way
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - app-network

  wordpress2:
    image: wordpress:latest
    container_name: wordpress2_ws-project
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser2
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass2
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb2
    volumes:
      - ./ws-project:/var/www/ws-project
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - app-network

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpass
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - app-network

  php:
    build: .
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./mugen-metrics:/var/www/mugen-metrics/
      - ./ukiyo-way:/var/www/ukiyo-way
      - ./ws-project:/var/www/ws-project
      - ./php-config:/usr/local/etc/php
      - ./php-logs:/var/log/php
    networks:
      - app-network
volumes:
  db_data:
  mugen-metrics:
  ukiyo-way:
  ws-project:
  nginx-config:
  nginx-logs:
  php-config:
  php-logs:

networks:
  app-network:

And this is my dockerfile to install mysqli in PHP
FROM php:8.1-fpm

# Install dependencies and necessary extensions for WordPress
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    default-libmysqlclient-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd mysqli pdo_mysql

# Clean up apt caches
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/


I tried to install manually but this is the message from php container
Installing shared extensions:     /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/
Installing header files:          /usr/local/include/php/
/usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-enable: 115: cannot create /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-mysqli.ini: Directory nonexistent


I don't know much about docker compose but are you sure you should be using default-libmysqlclient-dev?

I've tried with this dockerfile FROM php:7.4-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli but i have the error 502 bad gateway
